# Discount Combination Field Is Missing

Tags: shopify, discount

Discount Combination Field Is Missing

Why does the discount combination field not exist?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvd7C.png)

I cannot find any settings to enable/disable discount combinations...

Is this a Theme issue?

Thanks in advance for your responses!